# How do you cd to the directory of another screen window?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

gnome-terminal has a great feature where opening a new tab or window starts the new shell with cwd = the cwd of the previously-focussed window.

I usually run GNU screen in one of my gnome-terminal tabs.  Partly for the scrollback, partly for the compact and enumarated display of 5 to 10 windows, partly for the quick keystrokes to switch to a specific or the previous tab.

But I've been starting to wish I could cd in one window to the CWD of another window.  The question is, how?

(BTW, is a stackexchange Q&self-A an appropriate way to share a neat alias, shell function, or hack like this that I came up with?  I don't have a block, and I don't think twitter or facebook would be good options.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method is portable to any Unix system, but depends on the functionality of GNU bash's `cd -P` to make it not ugly.

Put this (or the other version below, that preserves logical directories) in your `~/.bashrc` (or `.zshrc` or whatever), so it runs for every interactive shell (inside and outside of screen):

```
CDS_PREFIX="/var/run/screen/S-$USER"  # screen uses this already
#CDS_PREFIX="/dev/shm/screen-$USER" # if /var/run isn't on tmpfs
# $STY = a string unique to the screen session
if [[ $STY ]]; then
        CDS_DIR="$CDS_PREFIX/dirs.$STY"
        unset CDS_PREFIX

        [[ -d $CDS_DIR ]] || mkdir -m 700 -p "$CDS_DIR"

        # old cmd-every-prompt design: avoids breakage if you run interactive bash from bash, then exit
        # Also, use this on systems without a /proc/<pid>/cwd
        #PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $WINDOW ]] && ln -sf "$PWD" "$CDS_DIR/$WINDOW"'

        ln -sTf "/proc/$$/cwd" "$CDS_DIR/$WINDOW"       # -T saves a stat call
        cds() { cd -P "$CDS_DIR/$@"; }
else
        # CDS_DIR=( "$CDS_PREFIX"/dirs.* )  # cds will use the first array element
        cds() { cd -P "$CDS_PREFIX/"dirs.*/"$@"; }  # even support shells started before screen.  cd with multiple args takes the first one without complaint.
fi
```

**So you can open a new screen window and `cds 5` will take you to the cwd of the shell in window 5.**

This even works for shells started OUTSIDE of screen, and even before your screen session existed.  (since in that case, the glob expansion happens at runtime of `cds`, rather than when it was defined like with the array-variable hack that I commented out, since it's worse in every way.)

Total overhead:

- on every interactive shell startup:
- - 8 non-comment lines of code to parse.
- - a stat
- - a ln -sTf to a directory on tmpfs
- ongoing memory overhead after shell starts:
- - 1 shell var and 1 tiny function
- - no environment vars
- storage:
- - a directory of one symlink per screen window (not removed after windows close)
- per command:
- - none

Without `cd -P`, the `\w` in your `$PS1` would expand to `/proc/3069/cwd`, rather than the canonical (symlinks followed) path you get with `-P`.

The version that uses PROMPT_COMMAND could modify `cds()` to cd to take you to the logical directory.  (Store CWD as text in a file, instead of in a symlink.  `pwd > "$CDS_DIR/$WINDOW"` is just a shell builtin, so less overhead than fork/execing a binary.  Also saves the trouble of working around missing GNU `readlink` on some non-Linux systems.)  This would be useful if you often work in symlinks to directories, where `pwd -P` (and `/bin/pwd`) isn't the same as `pwd`.

You could override the `cd`, `pushd`, and `popd` builtins with functions that update the symlink, instead of doing it EVERY prompt.  With that setup, interactive use of things like `(cd foo; command there)` will fool your setup, because the `cd` that runs in the subshell will update the symlink, but without modifying the pwd of the main shell process.

Ok, here's the "other version", that hooks `cd`, `pushd`, and `popd`, and will take you to the same logical directory as your shell in whatever screen window:

```
# Use this version on systems without `/proc/<pid>/cwd`, or for logical directories (non-dereferencing of symlinks).

CDS_PREFIX="/var/run/screen/S-$USER"
#CDS_PREFIX="/dev/shm/screen-$USER"
if [[ $STY ]]; then
    CDS_DIR="$CDS_PREFIX/dirs.$STY"
    unset CDS_PREFIX
    [[ -d $CDS_DIR ]] || mkdir -m 700 -p "$CDS_DIR"

    function cd    () { command cd    "$@"; pwd > "$CDS_DIR/$WINDOW"; }
    function pushd () { command pushd "$@"; pwd > "$CDS_DIR/$WINDOW"; }
    function popd  () { command popd  "$@"; pwd > "$CDS_DIR/$WINDOW"; }
    #PROMPT_COMMAND='[[ $WINDOW ]] && pwd > "$CDS_DIR/$WINDOW"'
    if [[ -e "$CDS_DIR/$WINDOW" && ! -f "$CDS_DIR/$WINDOW" ]]; then
        rm -f "$CDS_DIR/$WINDOW"  # could exist if switching from symlink-to-dir style
    fi
    cd .

#   cds() { local d="$(<"$CDS_DIR/$1")"; shift; cd "$d" "$@"; }
    cds() { cd "$(<"$CDS_DIR/$1")"; }
else
    # CDS_DIR=( "$CDS_PREFIX"/dirs.* )  # cds will use the first array element
    cds() { cd "$(<"$CDS_PREFIX/"dirs.*/"$1")"; }  # even support shells started before screen.
fi
```

Overhead: an `open(2)` and `write(2)` to tmpfs for every `cd`, `pushd`, and `popd` you type or paste in.  Otherwise the same.  Still not going to hurt, on any system powerful enough to run `bash` and `screen` in the first place. :)

Credit to https://superuser.com/a/54161/20798 for the idea of hooking cd.  I like that a LOT better than `PROMPT_COMMAND`.  Found that while looking to see if anyone else had invented this, and whether I should post here or on https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

I used some bash-isms (like `[[ ]]`) because I think zsh supports them too, and hopefully nobody is using POSIX sh as their interactive shell.