# What does the builtin command do in bash?

Tags: bash

I know what a builtin command is, but what does `builtin` itself do? Executing `which ls` shows me `/bin/ls`, but executing `which builtin` returns nothing.

`man builtin` just gives me a list of builtin commands, one of which is `builtin`. The rest of the man page explains what a builtin is, but not what `builtin` is.

`builtin --help` tells me `builtin: usage: builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]` but still not what it does.

Is it part of bash in a way that other builtin commands aren't?

Comment: You forgot `help builtin`.

Comment: `which builtin` returns no results, because `which` reports the location of *external commands*.  If you ask the shell `type builtin`, it will tell you, unsurprisingly, that `builtin is a shell builtin`.  You'll find the same with `alias`, `set`, etc.

Comment: `builtin help builtin`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `builtin` command makes sure you run the shell built-in version of the command rather than running another command with the same name.

For example, let's say you defined a shell function named `cd` to print some extra status everytime you change directories. But you messed it up and now you can't change directories correctly. So now you can type `builtin cd ~` to successfully cd back to your home directory without running your broken shell function.

And by the way, my copy of the bash man page has a section called "SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS", and it defines the meaning of the `builtin` command in that section (transcribed below).

```
builtin shell-builtin [arguments]

    Execute  the  specified  shell builtin, passing it arguments, and
    return its exit status.  This is useful when defining a function
    whose name  is the  same as a shell builtin, retaining the
    functionality of the builtin within the function.  The cd builtin is
    commonly  redefined  this  way.

    The  return status is false if shell-builtin is not a shell builtin
    command.
```

Comment: nice answer. But makes me wonder, how can you be sure that the `builtin` command is the real builtin from bash ?

Comment: I still understand his confusion, it could actually say - `shell builtin  function/command`, since without that they have to assume you know what a builtin is.

Comment: It is by design @Pacopaco since it is defined by the specific shell used.

Comment: @Pacopaco: You cannot :-). You _can_ override `builtin`, too: `function builtin { echo "Hi from builtin :-)"; }`. Then `builtin` no longer works.

Comment: And I don't think `builtin builtin` would then fix that

Comment: @Pacopaco, `type builtin` will tell you whether it's the real `builtin`.  Unless `type` has been replaced with a non-builtin `type`...

Comment: @TobySpeight: we need to go deeper!

Comment: Interrestingly: one can create a function "unset" and "unalias", but only "unalias" works: `unalias () { echo "A";} ; unset () { echo "B";} # then unalias unalias shows 'A', but unset unset just unsets "unset()" !)`. So you could "reliably" do :    `unset unset ; unset unalias ; unset builtin ; unalias builtin ; builtin something`

Comment: oh... unfortunately one can : alias unset="echo unset is overridden" ; alias alias="echo alias is overridden" ... So no luck here.

Comment: I love this ongoing discussion!

Comment: @OlivierDulac However `"unset"` (with quotes) won't be recognized as alias.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski ay yes; so there is hope ^^

Comment: But you can still use `\builtin`.

Comment: `builtin builtin builtin builtin builtin builtin builtin builtin` -> Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: `\builtin` only blocks alias expansion, not functions.  But yes, you could use `\unset builtin` and `\builtin` to restore sanity to a shell environment.

Comment: @spiff: If you messed up your override of `cd`, you'd just use `unset`.  You'd use `builtin cd` *as part of* a function wrapper for it.  e.g. [`cd () {  command cd "$@" && pwd > "$THIS_SCREEN_WINDOW_CURRENT_DIR"; }`](https://superuser.com/questions/874574/how-do-you-cd-to-the-directory-of-another-screen-window).  I used `command cd`, but `builtin cd` would have the same effect there.  Also, you don't even need the bash manual: run `help builtin`, like for any other shell built-in :P

Comment: @wjandrea : Nice comment.  Although, I only appreciated it because I was already familiar with Octo-buffalo.  (For anyone who isn't: [Wikipedia's article on Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo))